# Is it possible to add new subsciber to Aweber's list using its API?

Tags: php, aweber

I'm trying to add a new subscriber to Aweber's list using its API:
https://labs.aweber.com/docs/code_samples/subs/create
As, they have mentioned that it is possible.

But, how can i get below keys?
a) $accessKey
b) accessSecret
c) $account_id

Does it require the real Awebers' account? Please help in this regard.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign up for an account at http://labs.aweber.com, you will get those details in there.